# beancount not creating double entry transactions and postings to file

Tags: python, beancount

I am using [beancount 2.3.5](https://github.com/beancount/beancount/tree/2.3.5) and I am trying to write a proof of concept file that does the following:

1. Creates a simple chart of accounts
2. Posts sample transactions into ledgers using double entry

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal as D

import beancount.core.data as data

line_number = 42
metadata = data.new_metadata(filename='./myfile.beancount', lineno=line_number)

# define accounts
accounts = ["Assets:Bank", "Expenses:Groceries"]

# create postings
posting1 = data.Posting(accounts[0], data.Amount(D('1000'), 'USD'), None, None, None, meta=metadata)
posting2 = data.Posting(accounts[1], data.Amount(D('200'), 'USD'), None, None, None, meta=metadata)

# create transactions
transaction1 = data.Transaction(
    meta = metadata,
    date = datetime.strptime("2022-03-29", '%Y-%m-%d'),
    flag = "*",
    payee = "Bob's Grocery Store",
    narration = "Groceries for the week",
    tags = set(),
    links = set(),
    postings = [posting1, posting2]
)
```

After I run the code, I expect to see a newly created file `myfile.beancount` with the above transactions in it. However, no file is generated.

I suspect that I might have to mark the accounts as open first, but I can't see anywhere in the documentation (or a function/method in the source code) that provides a clean entrypoint to do that.

How do I modify this code so that it creates the file and correctly posts the transactions to the file?

Answer (score -1):

You are correct that in Beancount, accounts need to be opened before they can be used in transactions. To open an account, you need to create an Open directive for that account.

```
# create Open directives
open_directives = []
for account in accounts:
    open_directives.append(data.Open(
        meta=metadata,
        date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        account=account,
        currencies={'USD'},
    ))


#...

# write directives and transactions to file
entries = open_directives + [transaction1]
with open('./myfile.beancount', 'w') as f:
    f.write(loader.dumps(entries))
```